# numpy.where() does not consider the true condition

Tags: python, dataframe

When using numpy.where(), it does not consider the True condition. Here the time is like "165-12:40:45" and m_gear is of type int64 . Thanks for the tip.

### time         | m_gear

165-12:40:46 | 0 
165-12:40:47 | 1 
165-12:40:48 | 0 
165-12:40:49 | 1

the expected output is

## timeTake

165-12:40:45 
165-12:40:45 
165-12:40:48 
165-12:40:45

```
df_ts['timeTake'] = np.where(((df_ts['m_gear']==0) & (df_ts.m_gear.shift()== 1)), df_ts['time'],pd.to_datetime('165-12:40:45', format='%j-%H:%M:%S') )
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your question does not make sense without any data or expected output to go on.

Comment: Can you create a sample input output correctly formatted? Here this is kinda hard to help.

Comment: I have added the sample data and please let me know if you need any more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if i've caught your drift, but aren't you looking for (SettingWithCopyWarning fixed)

```
df_ts['timeTake'] = df_ts['time']
df_ts.loc[(df_ts['m_gear']!=0) | (df_ts.m_gear.shift()!= 1), 'timeTake'] ='165-12:40:45'
```

Comment: that serves the condition but it throws "SettingWithCopyWarning" and does not modify the attribute.

Comment: Right, I tend (wrongfully) to ignore this warning usually, you could handle it with (i'll modify the comment)

Comment: thank you @rotem .. the solution was perfekt and I fixed the warning.